# Connect to OpenVPN managed by NetworkManager using console

Tags: networking, gnome, network-manager, openvpn, 18.10

How do I connect to OpenVPN server managed by NetworkManager configured in Gnome settings using a command line?

[image: OpenVPN Profile in Gnome settings]

Is there a way to trigger this using command from a console?

I found out NetworkManager configurations are saved in `/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections` but how do I trigger them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's simple. Use the cli version of *network-manager* aka `nmcli`

List your available connection with

```
nmcli con
```

to get something like

```
NAME               UUID                                  TYPE      DEVICE 
Ethernet           bbc6713e-2050-4c68-a66b-98607eda7e87 ethernet  enp1s0 
PIA France         476c8d97-beb7-48b2-9922-55e3062d3db9  vpn       enp1s0 
tun0               bcfa5e83-b84f-4141-b146-d3b57d496fd4  tun       tun0   
theWifi            89326285-7b0e-48e6-a67c-ce28e38a062e  wifi      --     
PIA UK London      0c2841dc-cb62-437c-948d-b7b291544387  vpn       --     
PIA UK-S           3f60a5af-cc7e-45a5-b075-c5e2eb8bc075  vpn       --
```

Then you can use

```
nmcli con up 'PIA UK-S'
```

or

```
nmcli con up 3f60a5af-cc7e-45a5-b075-c5e2eb8bc075
```

Look for help with

```
nmcli help
```

Comment: Thanks :) It is actually `nmcli c up 'NAME'`.

Comment: oops sorry. corrected